# VB.NET Index '0' is out of range?

Tags: vb.net, indexing, range, out, inotifycollectionchanged

I made a ListBox in WPF with an `ItemSource` and with all those classes and events that make the UI refresh it. But there's a problem in my `Remove` method:

> `Public Sub Remove(ItemIndex As Integer)
>
>   MyList.RemoveAt(ItemIndex)
>
>   RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, MyList(ItemIndex)))
>
>   End Sub`

But when I execute this I get a message that the index (in this case `ItemIndex`) is out of range. But in the output window it says that the index is '0' (otherwise it would remove the item from `MyList`).

Comment: Well, if there are no items in the list, index `0` (which indexes the first item) will be out of bounds.

Comment: why do you need to raise the event programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I changed the code

> `Public Sub Remove(ItemIndex As Integer)
>
>   MyList.RemoveAt(ItemIndex)
>
>   RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, MyList(ItemIndex)))
>
>   End Sub`

into

> `Public Sub Remove(ItemIndex As Integer)
>
>   RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, MyList(ItemIndex), ItemIndex))
>
>   MyList.RemoveAt(ItemIndex)
>
>   End Sub`

That's all.